# How to stop a webpage from wrapping content?

Tags: php, html, css, overflow

I currently have been developing a test site [here](http://main.thanetparkour.com/jestressflo/) and my main monitor, that I've been using for debugging and whatnot is 1920x1080. My other monitor is 1280 x 720 and I am aware that not everyone in the world has even the second size.

I prefer my sites to work for all those that may view them and I would like this to be the minimal size but without affixing my entire page to ~1280 I am unsure on how to do this.

I have seen several websites that when the window is resized the web page remains the same and simply adds scroll bars. I would prefer this to happen on my test site.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've never searched this up but instead continued on and begun learning PHP etc. This just seemed to skip the boat.

I have tried floating `div`s but that really didn't work as I believe they are dependent on the window size.

Comment: have you tried CSS with a simple `overflow: auto`?

Comment: @jackJoe I have yes, I've realised that whatever way I go the navbar needs a redo :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#main-wrap {min-width: 1280px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `body {overflow: auto; width: 1280px;}`

Comment: I'm afraid of this, may mean redesigning bits like the navbar. This was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

So if I am understanding you correctly you are wanting to set a minimum width to your web page  without setting a maximum?

In that case you would need to set the min-width on your outermost container to 1280px and set the overflow to auto.